# Compare two Git branches without cloning

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-branch

With Git CLI can we compare two git branches **without cloning** anyone of them? (same repo)

e.g.
branches:

1. master
2. test_branch1
3. test_branch2

I want a command with the help of which I can compare something like:

```
git diff test_branch1 test_branch2
```

Comment: no same repository

Comment: I dnt wann clone any one of the branch, including master branch also.
simply login to terminal(in any random directory) and run "git diff" command will it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't clone branches, you clone the repository itself. If you want to compare remote branches, you can do:

```
git fetch
git diff origin/branch_1 origin/branch_2
```

If you don't want to get the files from the repo, you can do the following:

```
mkdir example
git init
git remote add origin <remote URL>
git fetch
git diff origin/branch_1 origin/branch_2
```

Comment: is there any way where we can avoid cloning repository also ?

Comment: @Maroun In what way `git fetch` is better than `git clone`? They are actually the same and the OP asked how to avoid it.

Comment: @phd I didn't say it's better, I just provided OP a solution of what they asked.

Comment: @Maroun You didn't The OP asked how to go without clone/fetch.

Comment: @phd Where's the "/fetch" part? `git fetch` and `git clone` are **not** the same.

Comment: @Maroun That returns us to my first question — in what way `git fetch` is better that `git clone`? For the OP question they are equally bad.

Comment: @phd I'm not sure what's good or bad for OP, if they state it's not a good solution, I'll edit. Thanks for your insight though, might be helpful for OP.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot run `git diff` locally without cloning or fetching commits. If you want to avoid `git clone/fetch` there are two options left.

If you have SSH access to the remote repository you can run `git diff` directly on the remote server:

```
ssh <user@origin-URL> """
    cd /path/to/repository &&
    git diff test_branch1 test_branch2
"""
```

If you don't have SSH access but there the repository is hosted at a server with web interface (you used tag [gitlab] in your question) then you can use the web interface to compare commits. For example: https://gitlab.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/compare/ed64be0ed032055b0a6613fe3051d83a74ded566...bebfdf9512ca6cdf94a3724dc2625a2288246945

If you have neither SSH nor web access your only option is to clone/fetch and run `git diff` locally.